# Determine structural equivalence of BSTs with standard traversal

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, tree, catalan

Is it possible to decide the structural equivalence of two binary search trees just with the results of traversals, pre order, in order and post order. Assume I have only the result arrays of all the traversals. I know in order traversal alone, can't help. But, I couldn't visualize for other traversal results. I understand BFS helps. I want to know for Pre and Post order traversals. And if possible, please post any links on this.

Comment: How do you define structural equivalence? Trees A and B are equivalent if A.key==B.key, and the A.left sub-tree is structurally equivalent to the B.left sub-tree, and the A.right sub-tree is structurally equivalent to B.right sub-tree?

Comment: @ Vaughn Cato: Yes, you are right. Assume I don't have the luxury of having both the trees simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, preorder works! you may also refer to [this page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-bst-from-given-preorder-traversa/) for C implementation of recovering a BST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is : **you can recover a binary search tree from its pre order traversal**.

I'm not sure what is your mathematical background so please ask if you need more explanation.

For simplicity, I'm assuming that the node are labeled by the integer 1,2... n where n is the number of node. Then the pre-order traversal of the tree t gives gives you a permutation of `[n] = {1,2,...,n}` which have a particular property: each time you have a letter b in your permutation, you can't find two consecutive letter `ca` after the `b` in the permutation such that `a<b<c`. Such a permutation is said to *avoid* the pattern `b-ac` (the - stand for an arbitrary number of letters).

For example, 4 2 1 3 avoids b-ac whereas 3 1 4 2 doesn't because 3 - 4 2.

This is actually an equivalence: A permutation is the pre order reading of a tree iff is avoid b-ac.

It is know that there are as many trees of size n as permutation avoiding b-ac so this is a bijection. Their number are know as Catalan number. You probably can find this as an exercice of Stanley's book "enumerative combinatorics".

**Here is a more algorithmic explanation**:

```
RecTree: Recovering a tree from is Pre-order traversal:

input: list l
output: tree t

b <- l[0]
find an index i such that 
   - for 1<=j<=i then l[j] < b and
   - for i<j<=n  then l[j] > b
if there isn't exists such an index return Failure
else return Node(key=b, RecTree(l[1..i]), RecTree(l[i+1..n]))
```

As a consequence

**Two binary search trees are equal if and only if they have the same pre order traversal**

Does it makes sense to you ?

Some more references

- [Catalan number in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A000108,)
- [Anders Claesson Generalized Pattern Avoidance, European Journal of Combinatorics 22 (2001) 961–971](http://combinatorics.cis.strath.ac.uk/download/Cl01__Generalized_Pattern.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Could you please elaborate the part, you can't find two consecutive letter ca after the b in the permutation such that aavoid the pattern b-ac (the - stand for an arbitrary number of letters). May be I couldn't get what do you mean by a, b,c. Like a < b < c ??

Comment: As you probably guessed, this is quite close to my research subject. So I had to answer this one.

Answer (score 0):

In a BST you can go left child (L), right child (R) or up (U). A traversal can then be described by a string over {L, R, U}, eg. "LLURUURLURUU". For BSTs with equivalent structures, these strings will be identical.